# Bad relocalization after motion tracking loss

Tags: google-project-tango

With my team we want to implement area learning for relocalization purposes in our projects.

I added this functionnality and it *seems* to work well. But when a drift disaster happens (motion tracking lost) and that the main camera is instantaneously projected in "the other side of the universe" the program doesn't succeed in relocalizing it : the camera is 2 meters below, or 3 meters beside than where it should be.

Is it an area description error (because it has got not enough point of interests) ?
Or I still have not understood how to use area learning ?

Thanks a lot.

P.S.:
I use the Unity SDK.

```
public void Update()
{
    TangoPoseData pose = new TangoPoseData ();
    TangoCoordinateFramePair pair;

    if(poseLocalized)
    {
        pair.baseFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION;
        pair.targetFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
    }
    else
    {
        pair.baseFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE;
        pair.targetFrame = TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
    }
    double timestamp = VideoOverlayProvider.RenderLatestFrame(TangoEnums.TangoCameraId.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);
    PoseProvider.GetPoseAtTime (pose, timestamp, pair);
    m_status = pose.status_code;

    if (pose.status_code == TangoEnums.TangoPoseStatusType.TANGO_POSE_VALID)
    {
        // it does not differ with the pair base frame
        Matrix4x4 ssTd = UpdateTransform(pose); 
        m_uwTuc = m_uwTss * ssTd * m_dTuc;
    }
}

public void OnTangoPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData pose)
{
    if (pose == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Relocalization signal
    if (pose.framePair.baseFrame == TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION &&
        pose.framePair.targetFrame == TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE)
    {
        poseLocalized = true;
    }

    // If pose status is not valid, nothing is valid 
    if (!(pose.status_code == TangoEnums.TangoPoseStatusType.TANGO_POSE_VALID))
    {
        poseLocalized = false;
        // Do I forget something here ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've regularly observed that the localization and re-localization of the Area Learning can produce x,y Pose coordinates off by a few meters.

Coordinates can be more accurate if I take more care in recording an area well before moving to a new area.

Upon re-localization the coordinate accuracy is improved if the tablet is able to observe the area using slow, consistent movements before traveling to a new area.

If I learn a new area I always return to a well known area for better accuracy as described by [drift correction](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/area-learning):

[image]

I have two Tango tablets using a Java app that is autonomously navigating an iRobot in my home.  I've setup a grid test site using 1 meter tape marks to make the observations.